# Are custom link attributes allowed?

Tags: html

Are custom link attributes allowed like "bid" in my example below? I need it for ajax calls. It works OK, I just want to be sure that it's legal.

```
<a href="#" class="morecomments" id="0-1" bid="1-1">Link</a>

$('.morecomments').live("click",function() {
var BID = $(this).attr("bid");
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they will work; but jQuery can also use `.data()` call to search for all attributes with `data-` prefix.

Read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/data/).